# Is "一些队员一样太好" correct?

Tags: grammar

> 一些队员一样太好。

Is this above sentence correct? My question is related to the existence of 太, which seems odd.

If it's wrong, how would I say "Some players are equally very good"?

Comment: I think a little more context might be needed. For example there's this video on QQ entitled: *小脸蛋跟果冻一样太好摸啦*, where the snippet 一样太好 is okay.

Comment: As an aside, I would consider *some players are equally very good* as waffle-language. You should rather say: *several players (of some group) are equally skilled*, which overall is easier to translate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 一些队员同样很好.

Some players are equally very good.

If you want to use  一样, then 一些队员也是一样很好的.

太 can not be used in comparing context, it is like the superlative, no others are good like them.

So you can say 一些队员太好了,  without a comparing adverb, like 一样, 同样, etc...

Comment: I liked you comment on 太 being like the superlative. How do you feel about 一些队员一样很好 then? I think the problem is having ANY intensifier there, no matter it's 太, 很, 非常...

Comment: Absolutely ok, 一样非常好， 一样极好，一样特别好 are all ok.  The difference is 一样  sounds more emphatic than 同样.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is ”一些队员一样太好“ correct?*

- '队员' implies the players are 'team members'. If you meant players of a team sport involving a ball, you should use '球员' ; If you meant players of an individual sport involving a ball, you should use '球手'. If a sport doesn't involve a ball, then the people who participate in that sport are not called 'player'
- '一样' could mean 'also'; '同样' is a better translation for 'equally'
- 太 doesn't mean 'very'. It means 'too ~' or 'overly'.
- 'very' in Chinese is: '非常', '很' or '十分'
- to describe a player as 'good', using '好' is too general (it could mean he is a good person). You should use a more specific term like '优秀/卓越 (brilliant)'  or '有才华'(talented)

> "some players are equally brilliant/ talented"
>
> "**一些球员同样非常优秀**"
>
> *一些 (some) | players (球员) | 同样 (are equally) | 非常 (very) | 优秀 (brilliant)*
>
> "**一些球员同样非常有才华**"
>
> *一些 (some) | players (球员) | 同样 (are equally) | 非常 (very) | 有才华 (talented)*

Other choices

"一些球员同样(十分)优秀"

"一些球员同样(很)优秀"

"一些球员同样(十分)有才华"

"一些球员同样(很)有才华"

Answer (score 2):

一些队员一样太好 doesn't sound right.

"Some players are equally very good" could be: 有些队员也非常不错 or 有些队员也非常棒.

Answer (score 2):

> 一些队员一样太好...

That's sounds odd; we don't say that.  You can say:

> 一些队员同样特别好

wherein

> 一样 = 同样
> 太 = 特别